# java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError for com.twitter.sdk.android.core.DefaultClient

Tags: android, gradle

I'm trying to integrate Digits by twitter in my existing project but just only adding its dependency is causing `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com.twitter.sdk.android.core.DefaultClient`.

After some searches, I found that gson might be causing the issue so I excluded gson where its older version is being used. Below are the dependencies I'm using in my existing project.

```
    compile 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:design:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:cardview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:23.0.1'
    compile 'com.android.support:palette-v7:23.0.1'

    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-plus:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:8.1.0'
    compile 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:8.1.0'

    compile 'com.github.paolorotolo:appintro:2.0.0'
    compile 'com.michaelpardo:activeandroid:3.1.0-SNAPSHOT'
    compile 'com.jakewharton:butterknife:7.0.1'
    compile 'com.squareup:otto:1.3.8'
    compile 'org.springframework.android:spring-android-rest-template:2.0.0.M1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:retrofit:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.squareup.retrofit:converter-jackson:2.0.0-beta1'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-fontawesome:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.joanzapata.iconify:android-iconify-material:2.1.0'
    compile 'com.github.bumptech.glide:glide:3.6.1'
    compile 'com.github.Musenkishi:Atelier:1.3.1'
    compile ('com.sromku:simple-fb:4.0.8'){exclude module: 'gson'}
    compile 'com.path:android-priority-jobqueue:1.1.2'
    compile 'uk.co.chrisjenx:calligraphy:2.1.0'
    compile('com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.1.0@aar') { transitive = true }
    compile('com.mikepenz:actionitembadge:3.1.2@aar') {transitive = true}
    compile 'com.sothree.slidinguppanel:library:3.1.1'
    compile 'com.github.xiprox.errorview:library:2.+'
    compile 'com.squareup.okhttp:logging-interceptor:+'
    compile('com.digits.sdk.android:digits:1.8.0@aar') {
        transitive = true;
    }
```

I'm still unable to fix the issue.
Any help would be highly appreciated.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With these many library saddles up, it must have exceded the infamous 64k method limit, you need to enable your app for multidex. 
Here is how you do it. 
https://developer.android.com/tools/building/multidex.html

Comment: Yes, I eventually ended up enabling multidex and it solved the issue.

Thanks